# how to cross docker-compose.yml file to link container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-composeA.yml

```
mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        - XXX=XXX
gogs:
    image: gogs/gogs
    links:
        - mysql:mysql # ok
```

docker-composeB.yml

```
tomcat:
    image: javaweb:8
    links:
        - mysql:mysql // wrong, can not find mysql defination
```

Now I want to link mysql container which defined in docker-composeA.yml, but when I run `docker-compose up` with docker-composeB.yml, it said 'mysql is undefined'. So How could I link container cross docker-compose.yml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`links` and `depends_on` both require a reference to a service defined in the same Docker Compose file. You need [`external_links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links).

Comment: I'm a docker beginner, thanks for your answer, it's right.

Comment: Glad it helped! So am I but I just happened to have a similar need a few days prior